# ACL Component + Cakephp2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

every thing is working properly only User Controller has problem with updating/saving which shows this error -

> AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => User [Aro0.foreign_key] => 1 ) "

This error normally shows when action is not authorized. How ever actions and pages are loading and the other Controllers doesn't have any problem with updating :(

I followed this tutorial - with Cakephp2.3 [CakePHP 2.1 AclComponent - Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIjfwqqGRhs)

Code [Download here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/59162477/AclComponent.rar)

resource [Acl controlled Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html)

Comment: Finally Got the answer ->For the other to know if you are using this code for you Auth - You shouldn't use 'Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'), in User Model :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using this code for you Auth -  in User Model You shouldn't use :)

```
'Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'),
```